# "Do you have a dog or a cat?"

Tags: conjunciones, preguntas, confusion

In English, it is common to see some variation of the following two sentences:

1. Are you now, or have you ever been, a member of the Communist party?
2. Are you friend or foe?

Because these are common statements, we know what to expect: Generally we expect a "yes" or "no" answer to #1, but we expect the answer "friend" or "foe" or "neither" to #2. (A smart-aleck or mathematician might answer "yes" to #2.) We can usually figure this out from context, but in a sentence like this, it's not totally clear:

- Do you have a dog or a cat?

I'm not sure whether you want me to answer "yes" vs. "no," or "dog" vs "cat" vs. "neither." Even in normal conversation, I think this is often confusing (although it usually doesn't matter very much). If you agree with this, **does this same confusion sometimes happen in Spanish?** How might we deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation is similar in Spanish.

- Do you have a dog or a cat?
- ¿Tienes perro o gato?

The answer here could be a simple "No", an ambiguous "Sí" or a specific answer like "No tengo ni perro ni gato", "Tengo (un) perro" or even "Pues tengo dos perros y tres gatos".